# Algebraic geometry introduction for homotopy theorists/algebraic topologists

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Algebraic geometry has a plenty of decent introductory texts now. Some are of the classical commutative algebraic approach(following EGA), like Ravi Vakil's "Foundations".

Some use facts from complex differential geometry, like "Principles of algebraic geometry" by Griffiths and Harris.

I wonder if there are some homotopy theoretic texts, aimed at people convenient with abstract algebraic topology and category theory.

Comment: I think that for a categorically-minded beginner Ravi Vakil's book should be ok (or maybe more traditionally Hartshorne's). In my experience the advantages of an homotopy-theoretic background arise when you start talking about stacks, which are a relatively advanced part of the subject. Also I am mildly amused at seeing "EGA" called "the classical approach" :)

Comment: As an algebraic topologist, I found (the first part of) "The Geometry of Schemes" by Eisenbud and Harris quite enjoyable.

Comment: Neil Strickland wrote a document called "Formal Schemes and Formal Groups" with this as one of its stated purposes: (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011121)

He also wrote "Functorial philosophy for formal phenomena", which covers some similar ground but is focused for reader who are already immersed in chromatic homotopy theory: (http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Strickland/fpfp.pdf)

Hitting stacks, the notes from Hopkins' course "Complex oriented cohomology theories and the language of stacks" become appropriate: (http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/coctalos.pdf)

Comment: However, I'd offer a personal caution that it's possible to take the "take only what you'll need" attitude too far; you don't need everything, but if you use algebraic geometry regularly a lot of time can be saved by being aware, in broad strokes, of the tools you're missing. It's easy to flail around relating cohomology of families of objects without knowing appropriate basechange theorems for cohomology. Grothendieck topologies are more fun when you state them in terms of covering families, but lead to a bunch of essentially irrelevant questions about exactly what should count as "a cover".

Comment: And so on. This advice applies generally to mathematics, but because algebraic geometry includes a large zoo of properties of mixed relevance to homotopy theory it seems to be easy to ignore too much.

Comment: Tyler, would you be willing to elaborate a bit more on your particular example regarding base change for cohomology theories? Is this just an observation along the lines of "Morava's change of rings isomorphism is part of a common phenomena"?

Comment: I found that realizing that the study of cohomology and sheaf cohomology is super different in AG as opposed to in AT is very helpful. Topologists use cohomology as a way to understand spaces. Number theorists use it to produce Galois representations with good properties (among other uses I am sure). In AG, I have been told that one resorts to the use of cohomology because of the existence of long exact sequences involving global sections of a sheaf. (I do not mean to limit the scope of uses of tools outside of my field just to indicate that they are different.)

Comment: @Sean The base-change example was more specifically related to a personal experience: a technical result I needed about cohomology of families of curves over a base that was solved completely by a (_very_) standard result that the derived pushforward along a proper map makes takes coherent sheaves to coherent sheaves. I'm not sure that more details are worthwhile.

Comment: @TylerLawson I would count this elaboration as more details. I had guessed incorrectly at what vein you might have been in.